# Oracle SQL - Change record presentation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can I change select record presentation from:

```
Ticket   Colour
12321    Green
12321    Blue
12321    Yellow
22653    Red
22653    Black
```

To:

```
Ticket   Colour1   Colour2   Colour3
12321    Green     Blue      Yellow
22653    Red       Black
```

Comment: Yes you can. Just check the dynamic pivoting in Oracle

Comment: use listagg function for it

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `LISTAGG` here:

```
 SELECT
    Ticket,
    LISTAGG(Colour, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Colour) AS Colours
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Ticket;

Ticket   Colours
12321    Blue,Green,Yellow
22653    Black,Red
```

The reason I suggest this is that perhaps your data set might eventually have more than 3 columns.  Dynamic SQL might get you around this, but it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ticket,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then colour end) as colour_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then colour end) as colour_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then colour end) as colour_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ticket order by ticket) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by ticket;
```

I should note that the ordering of the colors is not guaranteed.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Gordon, I receieved the same, and I have countered yours.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Maybe using `t` as both a source table name and a subquery alias caused that? Just a naive guess. Cant't see any other possible reasons at least :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Serial downvoting.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table ex(
no number,
colour varchar(20));

insert into ex values(12321,    'Green');
insert into ex values(12321   , 'Blue');
insert into ex values(12321   , 'Yellow');
insert into ex values(22653   , 'Red');
insert into ex values(22653   , 'Black');
select * from ex;

SELECT LISTAGG(colour, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY no)
FROM ex group by no;
```

output

```
12321   Blue, Green, Yellow
22653   Black, Red
```